# Showing recursive formula of integral?

Tags: integration, analysis

> I want to show the following equality:
>   $$\int_0^1\frac{x^n(x-1)^n}{n!}e^xdx=\int-\frac{x^n(x-1)^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}e^x-\frac{x^{n-1}(x-1)^n}{(n-1)!}e^xdx $$

So I thought
$$\begin{align}\int\frac{x^n(x-1)^n}{n!}dx&=\int-\frac{x^n(x-1)^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}-\frac{x^{n-1}(x-1)^n}{(n-1)!}dx\\&=\int\frac{x^n(x-1)^n}{n!}\cdot\underbrace{\frac{(1-x)^{-1}-x^{-1}}{(n-1)}}_{\text{=1?}}dx\end{align} $$

Looks similar to a telescope sum, but not exactly , does it really need to be 1 or do I nedd induction ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint. For $n\geq 1$, by integration by parts, we obtain
\begin{align*}\int_0^1\frac{x^n(x-1)^n}{n!}e^xdx&=\left[\frac{x^n(x-1)^n}{n!}e^x\right]_0^1-\int_0^1\frac{(x^n(x-1)^n)'}{n!}e^xdx\\
&=0-\int_0^1\frac{n(x^{n-1}(x-1)^n+x^{n}(x-1)^{n-1})}{n!}e^xdx.\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to add that there is a neat series solution to this problem as well. Using the binomial theorem with $(1-x)^n$ and series expansion for $e^x$, we have that

$$\int_0^1 \dfrac{x^n (x - 1)^n}{n!} e^x dx = 
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\sum_{j=0}^{n} \dfrac{(-1)^{n-j}}{(n-j)!\,j!\,k!\,(n+j+k+1)}$$

Not that it's very illuminating or anything, but it converges and is kinda cool.